# Laravel Auth check if url is equal to User Logged In

Tags: laravel

Hello so I've started using Laravel 5 and found it very useful. For now I am on the Auth part. What I want to do is the equivalent of this code in laravel:

```
if($_SESSION['user'] == $_GET['user'])
{
 // I can only see this page
}
```

This is what my function in my controller looks like:

```
public function viewProfile(User $user)
{
    $cur_user = \Auth::user()->username;
    return view('profile', compact('user', 'cur_user'));
}
```

And the url for example is like this `http://localhost:8000/profile/sorxrob`. The `sorxrob` there is the username. How can I do `Auth::user()` == Get url in laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware).

1. Create middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware OwnerMiddleware
```

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Article;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class OwnerMiddleware
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $currentUser = $this->auth->getUser();

        if (/* here goes your condition to check user*/) {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2. Add it to `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'owner' => 'App\Http\Middleware\OwnerMiddleware',
];
```

3. Use middleware in your routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['owner']], function() {
    // your route
});
```

Comment: to get current user in `handle()` method use `$this->auth->getUser()`. Just added this to the answer.

Comment: This is working.. one more question, in my template or the blade page.. How can a button be seen only by the logged in user?

Comment: @FewFlyBy `@if (Auth::check()) <button> @endif`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(Auth::user()->id == $user->id)
{
    $cur_user = \Auth::user()->username;
    return view('profile', compact('user', 'cur_user'));
}
```